# how do you find a parametrization of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ the lies between the planes $z=-1$ and $z=x^2+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

Since we are dealing with a cylinder, I thought it would be wise to use the [cylindrical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system).

Therefore

$x=rcos\theta$

$y=rsin\theta$

$z = x^2+y^2=r^2$

Therefore my final answer would be:

$r(r,\theta, z) = (rcos\theta, rsin\theta, r^2) $

But that seems like a parmeterization of just the cylinder, without the intersection of the plane and the paraboloid.

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: strange: if $z=x^2+y^2=1$, you have $z=1$ then the parameterization should be $(\cos(a),\sin(a,),1)$ ?!

Comment: the circle z=1 & $x^2+y^2=1$ is where the paraboloid and cylinder intersect. So I think you may have found the parametrization of the intersection of the paraboloid and the cylinder.  But I'm looking for the parametrization of the cylinder and the z=1 plane and the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$

Comment: Do you mean the "volumic cylinder" $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, not only its boundary $x^2+y^2=1$ ?

Comment: Yes, $x^2+y^2=1$ is a three dimensional cylinder that intersects the 3 dimensional plane z=-1 and the 3 dimensional paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ Here are some drawings of what I'm talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_(geometry)   and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid

Comment: The representation you are looking for is $r(r,\theta, z) = (rcos\theta, rsin\theta, z)$ with $-1<z<r^2$. You cannot do better than that.